# How to read DBF-file with GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, dbf

I get simple dbf files via e-mail. The file has the only table. I need to read the file into array and then change one column in the array, save dbf file and send back via e-mail.
How can I read and save\correct dbf with google app script?

Comment: I would not know how to do it directly, but there are APIs to convert dbf to csv or xls which are formats that can be read / converted with GAS.